# BBC Glow Sortable: custom animation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable, bbc-glow

I have implemented bbc glow sortable on my site. So, you can drag and drop items on the dashboard....like the bbc site! :)
Just wondering, does anyone know how I can customise the animation?

Currently when I click the item I can move it to another section and drop it. This fires an animation. I'm looking for a quick movement without the animation.

Cheers

Comment: Please provide sample code or a link to a working example

Comment: @devmatt: Hi, sorry I'm restricted on providing code from my solution, but this one shows what i am doing, its second from bottom: http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/1.7/furtherinfo/widgets/sortable/

Comment: Did you come right with this?

Comment: @devmatt - not yet, I still can't control the animation

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the draggable option `onAfterDrop` as per their documentation

"The default action is to animate the draggable back to it's start position. This can be cancelled by returning false from the listener or calling {@link glow.events.Event.preventDefault} on the {@link glow.events.Event} param."

```
new glow.widgets.Sortable(
    '#cols-example .col1, #cols-example .col2, #cols-example .col3',
    {
        draggableOptions : {
            handle : 'strong',
            onAfterDrop: function() {}

        }
    }
);
```